# how to close encrypted partition with nested partition table?

Tags: luks, cryptsetup

If I create an encrypted partition using cryptsetup

```
cryptsetup -q luksFormat /dev/vdb3 /tmp/pwfile
cryptsetup -d /tmp/pwfile luksOpen /dev/vdb3 pv00
```

and setup a nested gpt partition table on /dev/mapper/pv00

```
parted=/sbin/parted
disk=/dev/mapper/pv00
${parted} -s -- "${disk}" mklabel gpt
${parted} -s -- "${disk}" mkpart root 0% "${endp1}GiB"
${parted} -s -- "${disk}" mkpart swap "${endp1}GiB" "${endp2}GiB"
${parted} -s -- "${disk}" mkpart none "${endp2}GiB" "${endp3}GiB"
${parted} -s -- "${disk}" mkpart export "${endp3}GiB" 100%
```

then the new partitions are listed by `lsblk` as expected

```
root@clone:~# lsblk 
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
vda          254:0    0     8G  0 disk  
`-vda1       254:1    0     8G  0 part  /
vdb          254:16   0   128G  0 disk  
|-vdb1       254:17   0   126M  0 part  
|-vdb2       254:18   0   897M  0 part  
`-vdb3       254:19   0 120.6G  0 part  
  `-pv00     252:0    0 120.6G  0 crypt 
    |-pv00p1 252:1    0     8G  0 part  
    |-pv00p2 252:2    0     8G  0 part  
    |-pv00p3 252:3    0     8G  0 part  
    `-pv00p4 252:4    0  90.6G  0 part
```

but I cannot close the encrypted partition anymore:

```
root@clone:~# cryptsetup luksClose pv00
Device pv00 is still in use.
```

`dmsetup info -C` shows the nested partitions are not used, but /dev/mapper/pv00 is:

```
# dmsetup info -C
Name             Maj Min Stat Open Targ Event  UUID                                                   
pv00             252   0 L--w    4    1      0 CRYPT-LUKS2-f2a811407807491b875f414fa61f854d-pv00      
pv00p1           252   1 L--w    0    1      0 part1-CRYPT-LUKS2-f2a811407807491b875f414fa61f854d-pv00
pv00p2           252   2 L--w    0    1      0 part2-CRYPT-LUKS2-f2a811407807491b875f414fa61f854d-pv00
pv00p3           252   3 L--w    0    1      0 part3-CRYPT-LUKS2-f2a811407807491b875f414fa61f854d-pv00
pv00p4           252   4 L--w    0    1      0 part4-CRYPT-LUKS2-f2a811407807491b875f414fa61f854d-pv00
```

AFAIU the nested partitions keep pv00 busy.

Using lvm2 instead of a nested gpt partition table there is no such problem. I can deactivate the volume group using `vgchange -an vg00`, and pv00 can be closed as expected. Is there a similar command to decommission the nested gpt partition table on /dev/mapper/pv00 without removing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `kpartx`. Create the partition mappings with `kpartx -a /dev/mapper/pv00` and remove them with `kpartx -d /dev/mapper/pv00`. Otherwise you could only manually remove them with `dmsetup remove pv00p{1,2,3,4}`.

Why is this a problem anyway?

The kernel (device mapper, crypsetup/LUKS, LVM, ...) does not support nested partition tables at all. In theory, LUKS 2 could support multiple data segments / partitions on its own accord, but it was never implemented. So there is no support for any of it, end of story.

`parted` simply "cheats" by creating device mapper linear targets for them (technically the same thing LVM uses for its Logical Volumes). This is done without asking and `parted` offers no options to control this behavior whatsoever.

So it may look like there is support for this, but for the kernel, this isn't a partition table at all. Closing and reopening the LUKS device also does not make those partition devices reappear (unless you got some custom udev magic going). You'd have to re-run `parted` on it but even then they don't appear, because even `parted` expects this to be handled by another piece of software.

[parted NEWS file](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=parted.git;a=blob;f=NEWS;h=7cfca990647e23ce5c8a80d7d7ad950ad95c839f;hb=HEAD#l395) mentions it:

> - Noteworthy changes in release 3.1 (2012-03-02) [stable]
>   […]
>   Device-mapper devices ( LVM, dmraid ) no longer insert a 'p' between the
>   base device name and the partition number unless the last character of
>   the base device name is a digit.  This brings parted into compliance with
>   the partition naming of kpartx and "linux since the dawn of time", but
>   differs from the way that dmraid 1.0.0-rc16-3 operates.  A patch to
>   correct dmraid has been submitted to ataraid-list@redhat.com.  Without
>   this patch, parted and dmraid will both create duplicate partition devices
>   named /dev/mapper/foo1 and /dev/mapper/foop1.

It mentions `dmraid`, which is probably the reason why this functionality exists at all. You kind of want to support partition tables that can be found on fakeraid/dmraid setups. In this case, `dmraid` itself creates the partition devices, so `parted` doesn't have to; `parted` only updates them if you make changes to the partition table.

Nested partition tables aren't really a thing, if you use them anyway you'll have to depend on `kpartx` to manage them since `parted` only does so as a side effect.

Note that compatibility between `parted` mappings and `kpartx` is not entirely guaranteed. These are independent implementations.